# Ubuntu 20.04 on Mac Pro 2.1

Tags: mac

Good day

I got a Mac Pro 2.1 (flashed to 2.1 with OS X El Capitan) and wanted to install Ubuntu 20.04 x64 there. (No virtual machine etc) Only the Mac does not recognize my USB sticks somehow. The USB sticks were created with Etcher and Unetbootin. But I have already tried to refind with the bootloader. Unfortunately, it was unsuccessful.

greetings

Comment: I don't know much about Macs, but what about booting to bios and then boot to usb from the bios?

Comment: It works like that from my msi motherboard

Comment: The Mac Pro has no classic bios like normal PCs. I have read several times that the Mac Pro 2.1 does not support booting from USB sticks. But the tutorials I watched The USB boot worked without any problems

Comment: go follow the tutorial you found then

Comment: I have already done it but unfortunately without success ..

Comment: Too bad. I really don't know much about macs. Maybe call Apple support? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on an Xserve2,1 (=MacPro3,1) with native EFI boot. To be fair, I (somewhat?) cheated, I netboot iPXE.efi and have that load vmlinuz and initrd off the network, and nfsroot. But on principle, EFI 1.1 will boot UEFI binaries just fine. Unfortunately, the MacPro<3,1 generation only has a 32bit efi unlike mine, so what you’ll need to do is as follows:

Restore Ubuntu20.04 desktop .iso to a flash drive, unmodified. Do not use rufus or the like! Those alter the partition layout. The unaltered .iso is specifically prepared to allow EFI boot.

Once restored, open the EFI partition (mount partition 1 via gnome disks or /sbin/mount) and go to EFI/BOOT. Download https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/grub-efi-ia32-bin/download and extract it. Copy BOOTIA32.efi to EFI/BOOT (where youll also see BOOTX64) and grubia32.efi to EFI/ubuntu

Let me know if it works, I’m only recalling this from memory.

I do not recall if Ubuntu autodetects the 32bit efi boot, and installs grub-ia32, or if you need to install it via apt manually.